# Facebook login with either PHP or Javascript SDK not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

as the title states, I am having some trouble getting the user logged in on my Facebook application.

When the user is logged out, and they click `log in`, the page reloads and then displays a Facebook logo with the text `Go to Facebook.com` below it, and when I try using the Javascript SDK, I do get the login page in a popup box, but once I press `Login`, the popup redirects to a `XD Proxy` page, where I get stuck, and I have to manually close the popup to have the callback execute.

In both cases I get this error in the Chrome console,

Error I get in console, when using the Javascript SDK:

> **Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?etcetc...
>   from frame with URL
>   http://subdomain.mysite.com/folder/?etcetc...
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.**

Error I get in console, when using the PHP SDK:

> **Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/ from
>   frame with URL
>   https://www.facebook.com/login.php?etcetc...
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.**

Here is my code,

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'libs/facebook/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP ID',
  'secret' => 'SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  echo "<a href='".$logoutUrl."'>Login</a>";
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo "<a href='".$loginUrl."'>Login</a>";
}
?>
```

I am using version 3.0 of the PHP SDK.

After the PHP failed, I tried using the Javascript SDK instead, to handle the login and logout,

Javascript:

```
FB.init({
    appId       : 'APP ID',
    status      : true, // check login status
    cookie      : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml       : true // parse XFBML
}); 

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    if (response.session) {

        $('#login').hide();
        $('#logout').show();

    } else {

        $('#logout').hide();
        $('#login').show();

    }
});


$("#logout").live('click', function(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    }); 
});

$("#login").live('click', function(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    }); 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: its a Chrome security measure to stop cross domain requests ect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010170/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error-being-continuously

Comment: php code looks fine. Define `failed` please

Comment: This is why I hate the friggin' Facebook platform.

Comment: @Lawrence: So there is no way around it?

Comment: @zerkms: By `failed`, I mean that it didn't redirect me to the login page when I was logged out, and clicked on the login button to log in, it took me to a page with a Facebook logo with text below it stating `Go to Facebook.com`.

Comment: @user270311 i wouldn't know sorry, have a look at this http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Unsafe+JavaScript+attempt+to+access+frame+with+URL+http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com there's 53,700 results

Comment: Sometimes I get these errors one day and the next day it's gone without me doing anything...

Comment: @Lawrence: Thanx, I've checked out most of those already, but I'll have another look!

Comment: I used to get this, make sure the domain you are calling it from is the same as the one in the app settings.  Yes I hate working with Facebook too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after banging my head against the board for a while, I came up with this, and it does the trick!

Using the PHP SDK, it is redirecting the user to the login page if they are not logged in, and setting the `Logout` URL with the `next` parameter for later use wherever/whenever you want it.

And no more XSS errors! :)

```
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/your_app/'));
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/your_app/'));
    echo "<script>top.window.location='".$loginUrl."';</script>";
}
```

I hope this helps!