# Fill-in-the-blank quiz app... Client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, client-server

I've previously made a very simple fill-in-the-blank quiz app, using JS.  I'm now (for the first time) experimenting with a DB for signing in, saving profile and results, etc.  Should I run the fill-in-the-blank code on the client side after I deliver it? (i.e. getElementById than run code for each quiz topic before they see it)  Or should I try and run the code server side and deliver it already "blanked"?

After reading [Client-side logic OR Server-side logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516852/client-side-logic-or-server-side-logic) and [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation) the benefits seem to lean towards the server side.  Yet, I would like any answer a user types to verify when it is correctly written with no need for a submit button, which I've already written in JS.  It seems expensive to submit to the server with ever key press.  Does it really pose any security or cheating risk to do this client side?  Would it be slower?

Comment: You could validate with the server when the field is blurred. Validating answers client-side exposes all the correct answers to a curious user.

Comment: if it's for fun or entertainment, it's going to be easier and better for the user to do it all client side. If it's something official that stays on one's permanent record, server integrity outweighs the UX advantages the client offers.

Comment: It's more for fun.  I would like to hide the answers, and if it were to get popular I'd figure I could obfuscate them somehow, but no there's no real important security threat.  My main is concern is if it will be slower?

Comment: It'd most likely be faster to validate client-side since it doesn't require a round-trip to your server to check the result. If you're not concerned about people being able to determine the correct answers, then client-side validation works fine.